# How can I use CodeDom to create a decimal constant?

Tags: vb.net, decimal, constants, codedom

I have this function in my generator.

```
    Private Sub AddBoundedValue(ByVal boundedValue As Object, ByVal type As CodeTypeDeclaration, ByVal numericType As Type, name As String)

        If boundedValue IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim constant As New CodeMemberField(numericType, name)
            constant.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Const Or MemberAttributes.Public
            constant.InitExpression = New CodePrimitiveExpression(Convert.ChangeType(boundedValue, numericType))
            type.Members.Add(constant)

        End If

    End Sub
```

If a developer passes a decimal in for the "boundedValue" parameter and the decimal type for the "numericType" parameter the following code gets generated.

```
Public Const DollarAmountMaximumValue As Decimal = 100000
```

Despite the data type being passed into the constructor of the CodePrimitiveExpression object being a decimal, the code generated is an integer that gets implicitly converted and stored in a decimal variable. Is there any way to get it to generate with the "D" after the number as in:

```
Public Const DollarAmountMaximumValue As Decimal = 100000D
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not happy about this solution but unless someone has a better one I'll have to go with it.

```
Private Sub AddBoundedValue(ByVal boundedValue As Object, ByVal type As CodeTypeDeclaration, ByVal numericType As Type, name As String)

    If boundedValue IsNot Nothing Then

        Dim constant As New CodeMemberField(numericType, name)
        constant.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Const Or MemberAttributes.Public
        If numericType Is GetType(Decimal) AndAlso [I detect if the language is VB.NET here] Then
            constant.InitExpression = New CodeSnippetExpression(boundedValue.ToString & "D")
        Else
            constant.InitExpression = New CodePrimitiveExpression(Convert.ChangeType(boundedValue, numericType))
        End If
        type.Members.Add(constant)

    End If

End Sub
```